# How to use the API response in multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting response from API call. I will get all the datas and I stored that value in one varibale. How can I use that in multiple controllers without looping again and again.

- ) MainController.js

```js
$scope.responseData = reply.data;
```

This is my response. I am getting all records here. I am displaying all the records in a dashboard page based on this response.

I have 4 more controllers like,

- ) Controller1.js
- ) Controller2.js
- ) Controller3.js
- ) Controller4.js

First I have written in main controller like this,

```js
$timeout(function(){
$scope.responseData.forEach(function (data) {
   if (data.Category == 'A') {
    console.log("A");
   } else if (data.Category == 'B') {
    console.log("B");
   } else if (data.Category == 'C') {
    console.log("C");
   }else if (data.Category == 'D') {
    console.log("D");
   }
  });       
});
```

I want to use this in multiple controller. Right now I am writing this condition in all controllers. So multiple time same loop is going and application is getting slow.

**Controller1.js :**

```js
$timeout(function(){
$scope.responseData.forEach(function (data) {
   if (data.Category == 'A') {
    console.log("A");
   } else if (data.Category == 'B') {
    console.log("B");
   } else if (data.Category == 'C') {
    console.log("C");
   }else if (data.Category == 'D') {
    console.log("D");
   }
  });       
});
```

**Controller2.js :**

```js
$timeout(function(){
$scope.responseData.forEach(function (data) {
   if (data.Category == 'A') {
    console.log("A");
   } else if (data.Category == 'B') {
    console.log("B");
   } else if (data.Category == 'C') {
    console.log("C");
   }else if (data.Category == 'D') {
    console.log("D");
   }
  });       
});
```

**Controller3.js :**

```js
$timeout(function(){
$scope.responseData.forEach(function (data) {
   if (data.Category == 'A') {
    console.log("A");
   } else if (data.Category == 'B') {
    console.log("B");
   } else if (data.Category == 'C') {
    console.log("C");
   }else if (data.Category == 'D') {
    console.log("D");
   }
  });       
});
```

**Controller4.js :**

```js
$timeout(function(){
$scope.responseData.forEach(function (data) {
   if (data.Category == 'A') {
    console.log("A");
   } else if (data.Category == 'B') {
    console.log("B");
   } else if (data.Category == 'C') {
    console.log("C");
   }else if (data.Category == 'D') {
    console.log("D");
   }
  });       
});
```

How to write only one place and use in multiple places. Can anyone please explain me.

Comment: do you have a service?

Comment: Use a service to make the API call, store data and inject it in each of the controllers, that is the standard way to share data among controllers in AngularJS